# Only show changes after JS function ends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some JavaScript that runs after a successful AJAX call:

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "CalendarServices.aspx/UpdateFilter",
       data: 'id=' + this.value + '&checked=' + $(this).is(':checked'),
       success: function (data) {
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       }
       ,
       error: function () {
       }
   });
```

I do not want the user to visually see the changes of  `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');`until  `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` has been called... is that possible?

This is because I inject some html in a callback for  `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` that gets destroyed when resources are fetched, so there is a small flicker.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: use some delay   between those two

Comment: How is the callback called? Maybe you can do 
setTimeout(0, $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources'));

Comment: Did you try setting a `loading` callback? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/loading/